# How do you combine multiple filters in isotope JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have two content type areas which contain unique filter options. These are:

1. `type`
2. `tag`

I'm trying to utilise [isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/), to achieve a dual filtering layout, but it always gives the last clicked filter priority.

See use case here (reference below demo):

1. If I click "Blog & News", I should see two posts (works)
2. If I then also click "Case studies", I should see both case studies and blog posts. Any item that is checked should show in the listing.

The filters in combination isn't working.

The documentation says the `arrange()` method can handle multiple filter instances, but it isn't working in my use case.

I've also tried using the `concatValues()` function to concatenate the values (as shown in many demos), but it still doesn't yield the correct results.

[See interactive demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/9rj0svm3/).

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var gridItems = container.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
  const optionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.rSidebar__options-li');

  var iso = new Isotope(container, {
    itemSelector: '.resourceCard',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    transitionDuration: '0.5s',
  });

  var filters = {};

  function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
      value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
  }

  function handleFilterClick(event, filters, iso) {
    var listItem = event.target;
    var filterGroup = listItem.closest('.rSidebar__options').getAttribute('data-filter-group');
    var filterValue = listItem.getAttribute('data-filter');

    if (filters[filterGroup] === filterValue) {
      delete filters[filterGroup];
    } else {
      filters[filterGroup] = filterValue;
    }

    // Combine filters
    var filterValues = Object.values(filters).join(', ');
    // var filterValues = concatValues( filters );


    // debugging
    console.log('List Item:', listItem);
    console.log('Filter Group:', filterGroup);
    console.log('Filter Value:', filterValue);
    console.log('Filters Object:', filters);
    console.log('Filter Values:', filterValues);

    iso.arrange({ filter: filterValues });
  }

  optionLinks.forEach(function(optionLink) {
    optionLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.classList.toggle('selected');
      handleFilterClick(event, filters, iso);
    });
  });


});
```

```css
.post {
  padding: 100px;
}

.rSidebar__box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.rSidebar__options {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.rSidebar__options-li {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}
.rSidebar__options-li.selected .rSidebar__options-square {
  background-color: #185A7D;
}
.rSidebar__options-square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.rSidebar__options-label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -14px;
}
.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(33.33% - 14px);
  margin: 14px 0 18px 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <!-- SIDEBAR -->
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="rSidebar">

          <!-- tags -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by tag</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="type">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".pdf">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".pdf">PDF</span>
              </li>
                <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".article">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".article">Article</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!--  type -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by type</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="type">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".blogs-and-news">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".blogs-and-news">Blog & News</span>
              </li>
                <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".case-study">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".case-study">Case Studies</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

      <!-- GRID -->
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="grid">
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item case-study pdf"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Case study, PDF post</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Blogs and news post</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news article"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Blogs and news, article post</span></article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Latest attempt

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var gridItems = container.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
  const optionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.rSidebar__options-li');

  var iso = new Isotope(container, {
    itemSelector: '.resourceCard',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    transitionDuration: '0.5s',
  });

  var filters = {};

  function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
      value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
  }

  function handleFilterClick(event, filters, iso) {
    var listItem = event.target;
    var filterGroup = listItem.closest('.rSidebar__options').getAttribute('data-filter-group');
    var filterValue = listItem.getAttribute('data-filter');

    var allowMultiple = listItem.closest('.rSidebar__options').getAttribute('data-multiple') === 'true';

    if (allowMultiple) {
      // toggle the filter value
      if (filters[filterGroup] && filters[filterGroup].includes(filterValue)) {
        // remove the filter value if it already exists
        filters[filterGroup] = filters[filterGroup].filter(value => value !== filterValue);
      } else {
        // add the filter value if it doesn't exist
        if (!filters[filterGroup]) {
          filters[filterGroup] = [];
        }
        filters[filterGroup].push(filterValue);
      }
    } else {
      // replace the filter value
      filters[filterGroup] = [filterValue];
    }

    var filterValues = concatValues( filters );

    // console.log('List Item:', listItem);
    // console.log('Filter Group:', filterGroup);
    // console.log('Filter Value:', filterValue);
    // console.log('Filters Object:', filters);
    // console.log('Filter Values:', filterValues);

    iso.arrange({ filter: filterValues });

  }


  optionLinks.forEach(function(optionLink) {
    optionLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.classList.toggle('selected');
      handleFilterClick(event, filters, iso);
    });
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the object value which is created whenever the tag/type is clicked with value selected and then use that updated array to pass in filter.

In below code I have added condition i.e : if there is selected class on the target element then only add/update the value of array (*filters*) else just remove that *data-filter* value from the key.

***Demo Code :***

```js
var filters = {};
var container = document.querySelector('.grid');
var gridItems = container.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
const optionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.rSidebar__options-li');

var iso = new Isotope(container, {
  itemSelector: '.resourceCard',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  transitionDuration: '0.5s',
});

function concatValues(obj) {
  var value = [];
  for (var prop in obj) {
    value.push(obj[prop]);
  }

  return value.flat().join(', ');
}

function handleFilterClick(event, filters) {
  console.clear()
  var listItem = event;
  var filterGroup = listItem.closest('.rSidebar__options').getAttribute('data-filter-group');
  var data_filter = listItem.getAttribute('data-filter');

  //if selected class present do below : 
  if (listItem.classList.contains('selected')) {
    if (!filters[filterGroup]) {
      filters[filterGroup] = []
    }
    filters[filterGroup].push(data_filter)
  } else {
    filters[filterGroup] = filters[filterGroup].filter(data => data !== data_filter)
  }
  var filterValues = concatValues(filters);
  console.log(filterValues)

  iso.arrange({
    filter: filterValues
  });
}

optionLinks.forEach(function(optionLink) {
  optionLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
    handleFilterClick(this, filters);
  });
});
```

```css
.post {
  padding: 100px;
}

.rSidebar__box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.rSidebar__options {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.rSidebar__options-li {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}

.rSidebar__options-li.selected .rSidebar__options-square {
  background-color: #185A7D;
}

.rSidebar__options-square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

.rSidebar__options-label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -14px;
}

.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(45% - 14px);
  margin: 14px 0 18px 14px;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <!-- SIDEBAR -->
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="rSidebar">

          <!-- tags -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by tag</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="tag">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".pdf">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".pdf">PDF</span>
              </li>
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".article">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".article">Article</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!--  type -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by type</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="type">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".blogs-and-news">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".blogs-and-news">Blog & News</span>
              </li>
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter=".case-study">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block buttonTemp" data-filter=".case-study">Case Studies</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

      <!-- GRID -->
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="grid">
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item case-study pdf"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Case study, PDF post</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Blogs and news post</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news article"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Blogs and news, article post</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news article pdf case-study"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Blogs and news,article,pdf,case study </span></article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Swati, thanks for your answer. However, it seems like your demo showcases results that exactly match the `filterValue` results. For example, see this JSFiddle here based on your demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7f6ujL9t/. In this snippet, if you click the following options "blogs & news", "article" and "pdf". This doesn't show any results, when infact, it should show the "Blogs and news,article,case study" post because it has 2 of the filters ("blog & news" and "article")

Comment: See video demo here of my above message: https://i.imgur.com/MtBWXcB.mp4

Comment: Hi , I am getting confuse because in your asked question you said `If I then also click "PDF", I should then see no posts (as no blog post that has pdf as a class exists)..` what does this mean then ?

Comment: Apologies Swati, it seems I got confused myself at the time of writing the question and noted an incorrect use case. To clarify, the filters are "checkboxes" in nature, and any that are `.selected` should show in the results. I.e. if blogs and case studies are checked, then it should show both of them (rather than results that have both `.blogs-and-news.case-studies` assigned. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes @Freddy . Please check if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Hi Swati, what you've done there is exactly what I needed in the above defined use case. Though the requirement / logic has changed since your answer. As you've answered the original question, I will mark this as the answer (thanks for the assist). But, also wondering if you could help me with the modified use case, which I've detailed in a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77217964/using-isotope-js-to-define-an-and-relationship-when-filtering-using-multiple-opt