# Using isotope.js to define an AND relationship when filtering using multiple options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-isotope

I have two content type areas which contain unique filter options. These are:

1. `type`
2. `tag`

I'm trying to utilise [isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/), to achieve a dual filtering layout, but it always gives the last clicked filter priority.

The way I want it to function is:

1. If only one `tag` is selected, then show results with that `tag`
2. If more than one `tag` is selected, then show results that have any of those tags (both do not need to exist together on a card)
3. If a `type` is selected, only show results that fall under that `type`
4. If one `type` is selected and one `tag`, show results for posts where the `tag` exists on the selected `type`
5. If one `type` is selected and multiple `tags`, then show posts that fall under that type that have either of those `tags`.
6. If more than one `type` is selected and one or more `tag`s, then show posts where the `tag`s exist on either type

For example, using my demo below, here are some use cases:

1. If I click on "Video Demos & Tours", I should see two video posts (card 1 and 3) - WORKS
2. If I click on "Video Demos & Tours" and then "Ansible", I should see only see card 3 - DOESN'T WORK
3. If I click on "Blog & News", I should see 3 cards (card 2, 4, 5) - WORKS
4. If I click on "Blog & News" and then "Ansible", I should see cards 4 and 5
5. If I click on "Blog & News", "Ansible" and then "Automation", I should see cards 2,4 and 5

However, in my current demo, though the console log seems to be on the right lines, it doesn't perform the way I intent it to.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var container = document.querySelector(".grid");
  var gridItems = container.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
  const optionLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".rSidebar__options-li");

  var iso = new Isotope(container, {
    itemSelector: ".resourceCard",
    layoutMode: "fitRows",
    transitionDuration: "0.5s"
  });

  var filters = {};

  function concatValues(obj) {
    var value = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
      value.push(obj[prop]);
    }
    return value.flat().join(", ");
  }

  function handleFilterClick(event, filters) {
    var listItem = event;
    var filterGroup = listItem
      .closest(".rSidebar__options")
      .getAttribute("data-filter-group");
    var data_filter = listItem.getAttribute("data-filter");

    if (filterGroup === "type") {
      filters[filterGroup] = [data_filter];
    } else {
      if (!filters[filterGroup]) {
        filters[filterGroup] = [];
      }

      if (listItem.classList.contains("selected")) {
        filters[filterGroup].push(data_filter);
      } else {
        filters[filterGroup] = filters[filterGroup].filter(
          (tag) => tag !== data_filter
        );
      }
    }

    // Combine the type filter with the selected tag filters using an AND relationship
    var filterValues = [];

    // Handle type filter
    if (filters["type"]) {
      filterValues.push("." + filters["type"][0]);
    }

    // Handle tags filter if it's defined
    if (filters["tag"]) {
      var selectedType = filters["type"][0];
      filters["tag"].forEach((tag) => {
        filterValues.push("." + selectedType + "." + tag);
      });
    }

    var finalFilter = filterValues.join(", ");
    console.log(finalFilter);

    iso.arrange({
      filter: finalFilter
    });
  }

  optionLinks.forEach(function (optionLink) {
    optionLink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.classList.toggle("selected");
      handleFilterClick(this, filters);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.post {
  padding: 100px;
}

.rSidebar__box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.rSidebar__options {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.rSidebar__options-li {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}
.rSidebar__options-li.selected .rSidebar__options-square {
  background-color: #185A7D;
}
.rSidebar__options-square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.rSidebar__options-label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -14px;
}
.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(45% - 14px);
  margin: 14px 0 18px 14px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <!-- SIDEBAR -->
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="rSidebar">

          <!-- tags -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by tag</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="tag">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="ansible">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="ansible">Ansible</span>
              </li>
                <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="automation">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="automation">Automation</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!--  type -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by type</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="type">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="blogs-and-news">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="blogs-and-news">Blog & News</span>
              </li>
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="video-demos-tour">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="video-demos-tours">Video Demos & Tours</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

      <!-- GRID -->
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="grid">
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item video-demos-tour automation"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 1<br>Type: Video Demo & Tour<br>Tag: Automation</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 2<br>Type: Blog & News<br>Tag: Automation</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item video-demos-tour automation ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 3<br>Type: Video Demo & Tour<br>Tags: Automation, Ansible</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 4<br>Type: Blog & News<br>Tag: Ansible</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 5<br>Type: Blog & News<br>Tags: Ansible, Automations</span></article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to combine filters of the same group with OR and between groups with AND:

```
{a,b} x {1,2} -> a1|a2|b1|b2
```

In selectors (as used by Isotope), that would be:

```css
.a.1, .a.2, .b.1, .b.2
```

You can build this by going over each group, combining every element with the previously build selectors:

```
function buildSelectors(filterObject){
  return Object.values(filterObject)  // extract filter arrays
    .reduce(
      (selectors, groupValues) => 
        groupValues.length === 0 ? selectors :  // skip empty groups
        groupValues.flatMap(v => selectors.map(s => `${s}.${v}`)) // combine group elements with existing selectors into new list
      , [''])
    .join(', ')
}
```

If you prefer regular loops, that is something like:

```
function buildSelectors(filterObject){
  let selectors = ['']
  for (const group of Object.values(filterObject)){
    if (group.length === 0) {
      continue
    }
    const mergedSelectors = []
    for (const value of group) {
      for (const selector of selectors) {
        mergedSelectors.push(`${selector}.${value}`)
      }
    }
    selectors = mergedSelectors
  }
  return selectors.join(',')
}
```

---

Some general hints and recommendations:

- Card 2 and Card 5 miss the `automation` class, not sure if that is intentional
- Instantiate the `filter` object with empty arrays for all existing groups, it spares you figuring out if the group property already exists later on
- Separate DOM operations from filter data operations, it makes the code more maintainable
- Consider creating a class for filter to further split up the code by concern

Have a look at the updated snippet:

```js
class Filter{
  groups = {
    tag: [],
    type: [],
  }
  
  updateGroup(group, value, isSelected) {
    const isActiveValue = this.groups[group].includes(value)
    if (isSelected && !isActiveValue){
       this.groups[group].push(value)
    }
    if (!isSelected && isActiveValue){
       this.groups[group] = this.groups[group].filter(v => v !== value)
    }
  }

  buildSelector(){
    return Object.values(this.groups).reduce(
      (selectors, groupValues) => 
        groupValues.length === 0 ? selectors :
        groupValues.flatMap(v => selectors.map(s => `${s}.${v}`))
      , [''])
    .join(', ')
  }
  
  updateSelector(group, value, isSelected){
    this.updateGroup(group, value, isSelected)
    return this.buildSelector()
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

  const iso = new Isotope('.grid', {
    itemSelector: ".resourceCard",
    layoutMode: "fitRows",
    transitionDuration: "0.5s"
  });

  const activeFilter = new Filter()
  
  function onOptionLinkClick(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    this.classList.toggle("selected");
    const isSelected = this.classList.contains("selected")
    
    const group = this
      .closest(".rSidebar__options")
      .getAttribute("data-filter-group");
    const value = this.getAttribute("data-filter");

    const filter = activeFilter.updateSelector(group, value, isSelected)
    iso.arrange({filter})
    
    console.clear()
    console.log('Current filter:', filter)
  }

  const optionLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".rSidebar__options-li");
  optionLinks.forEach(optionLink => optionLink.addEventListener("click", onOptionLinkClick));
})
```

```css
.post {
  padding: 10px;
}

.rSidebar__box {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.rSidebar__options {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.rSidebar__options-li {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: fit-content;
}
.rSidebar__options-li.selected .rSidebar__options-square {
  background-color: #185A7D;
}
.rSidebar__options-square {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.rSidebar__options-label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -14px 0 0 -14px;
}
.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(45% - 14px);
  margin: 14px 0 18px 14px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="post">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">

      <!-- SIDEBAR -->
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="rSidebar">
          
          <!-- tags -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by tag</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="tag">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="ansible">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="ansible">Ansible</span>
              </li>
                <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="automation">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="automation">Automation</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <!--  type -->
          <div class="rSidebar__box">
            <span class="rSidebar__label d-block fw-bold">Filter by type</span>
            <ul class="rSidebar__options button-group" data-filter-group="type">
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="blogs-and-news">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="blogs-and-news">Blog & News</span>
              </li>
              <li class="rSidebar__options-li" data-filter="video-demos-tour">
                <span class="rSidebar__options-square"></span>
                <span class="rSidebar__options-label d-block" data-filter="video-demos-tours">Video Demos & Tours</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- end -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

      <!-- GRID -->
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="grid">
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item video-demos-tour automation"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 1<br>Type: Video<br>Tag: Automation</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news automation"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 2<br>Type: Blog<br>Tag: Automation</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item video-demos-tour automation ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 3<br>Type: Video<br>Tags: Automation, Ansible</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 4<br>Type: Blog<br>Tag: Ansible</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item blogs-and-news ansible automation"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 5<br>Type: Blog<br>Tags: Ansible, Automation</span></article>
          <article class="resourceCard grid-item video-demos-tour ansible"><span class="resourceCard__body-title">Card 6<br>Type: Video <br>Tags: Ansible</span></article>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does that make sense, does it help?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but this is exactly what I was after! Thanks!